# Headless chrome in Docker "symbol not found" error after latest update

Tags: docker, google-chrome-headless

I have a Docker container that I've been using for quite some time for a node application which depends on headless chrome. This container has always worked up until just now, without changing anything.

The container builds fine, but chromium has an error when it is started within the container:

```
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC2ERKS4_mRKS3_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt19_Sp_make_shared_tag5_S_eqERKSt9type_info: symbol not found
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine

# Install git
RUN apk --no-cache upgrade
RUN apk --no-cache add git

# Install chromium
RUN apk -U --no-cache \
    --allow-untrusted add \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium \
    xvfb \
    wait4ports \
    xorg-server \
    dbus \
    ttf-freefont \
    grep \
    udev \
    && apk del --purge --force linux-headers binutils-gold gnupg zlib-dev libc-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/* \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/doc \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/html \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/scripts

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
ENV CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/

# Bundle app files
ADD ./dtms-api-service /server/dtms-api-service
ADD ./dtr-omnicache /server/dtr-omnicache
ADD ./dtr-webservice /server/dtr-webservice
ADD ./env.json /env.json
ADD ./env-dev.json /env-dev.json
ADD ./ecosystem.config.js /ecosystem.config.js

# Install app dependencies
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
RUN cd /server/dtms-api-service && npm install
RUN cd /server/dtr-omnicache && npm install
RUN cd /server/dtr-webservice && npm install

EXPOSE 3001

ENV PM2_PUBLIC_KEY <secret>
ENV PM2_SECRET_KEY <secret>

CMD ["sh", "-c", "chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-software-rasterizer --remote-debugging-port=9222 & pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production"]
```

I've also tried using this to install chrome but it makes the same result:

```
# Install chromium
RUN echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk add --no-cache \
      chromium@edge \
      nss@edge
```

As well as:

```
# Install chromium
RUN echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    chromium@edge \
    harfbuzz@edge \
    nss@edge \
    freetype@edge \
    ttf-freefont@edge \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/* \
    && mkdir /var/cache/apk
```

EDIT: So it turns out that Chromium was updated on the APK repository on the 25th of September, which would line up with the time it stopped working. So now I have to figure out how to get it working again or switch to the older version.

I tried installing the previous version using:

```
RUN echo @v3.10 http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo @v3.10 http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    chromium@v3.10 \
    harfbuzz@v3.10 \
    nss@v3.10 \
    freetype@v3.10 \
    ttf-freefont@v3.10 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/* \
    && mkdir /var/cache/apk
```

And now with this I get a segmentation fault when running the `chromium-browser` command.

Answer (score 4):

Also bumped into this one few days ago. I suspect the edge version of chrome is broken. Historically the reason for me to using that was because of the new `--headless` option. But the [stable build](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/chromium) is currently at *77.0.3865.75-r0*, which is more than enough for everything I needed. So my `Dockerfile` now looks like this:

```
...
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  apk add --no-cache \
  chromium
...
```

The use-case for me is to build [EmberJS](https://emberjs.com/) app and test it against Chrome in *headless* mode.

Before this change my `Dockerfile` that was not longer working for me was:

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --no-cache \
  git \
  chromium@edge \
  nss@edge \
  freetype@edge \
  harfbuzz@edge && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  /var/cache/apk/* \
  /usr/share/man \
  /tmp/*
```

And the error was:

```
            Error: Browser exited unexpectedly
            Non-zero exit code: 127
            Stderr: 
             Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
            Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
            Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt19_Sp_make_shared_tag5_S_eqERKSt9type_info: symbol not found
```